# Test report gets overwritten

Tags: spring, unit-testing, gradle, integration-testing

I have unit tests and integration tests in my project which are separated by @Category so they can be executed in order:

```
test {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories '....UnitTest'
    }
}

task itTest(type: Test, dependsOn: tasks.test) {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories '....IntegrationTest'
    }
}
```

Running the task itTest executes the unit tests first and the integration tests second as desired but the unit test reports are not included in the summary. [This](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#subProjectsTestReport) suggests there is a solution to this problem but I am not sure how to include that snippet into my build.gradle. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in newer Gradle versions (> 3.0 I think) the path to the test report includes the task name so it avoids overriding results. For earlier gradle versions you can set the report path manually to avoid having multiple tasks using the same report folder. e.g like:

`itTest.reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/itTest")`